# @KafkaListener skipping messages when using Acknowledgment.nack()

Tags: spring-kafka

*Spring Kafka version - 2.8.5*

````
```@KafkaListener
        consumeMessages(@Payload List<String> messages,Ack ack)
        {
        //process records in separate Thread and acknowledge
        // Thread is not available nack it after 2 seconds
        }```
````

**Nack records should be reprocessed after 2 seconds in KafkaListener. However, Skipped records were not processed by KafkaListener. The missing message is consumed again after restarting the Spring Boot app.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `nack()` from another thread; only from the listener thread

```java
@Override
public void nack(long sleepMillis) {
    Assert.state(Thread.currentThread().equals(ListenerConsumer.this.consumerThread),
            "nack() can only be called on the consumer thread");
```

Even when called from the listener thread, `nack()` does not support "skipping" records; when using manual commits, it is the application's responsibility to commit the offset to skip a record (by calling `acknowledge()`).